# How to call into python script like a function from bash?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a `build.sh` script that my automated build server executes as part of a build. A big portion of logic of the build is calculating and building a version number. All of this logic is in a python script such as `calculate-version.py`.

Typically what I would do in this case is setup the python script to ONLY print the version number, from which I would read stdout from the bash script, and assign that to an environment variable. However, the python script is becoming sufficiently complex that I'd like to start adding logs to it.

I need to be able to output (stdout) logs from the Python script (via `print()`) while at the same time when it is done, propagate a "return value" from the python script back to the parent shell script.

What is the best way of doing this? I thought of doing this through environment variables, but my understanding is those won't be available to the parent process.

Comment: You might want to log somewhere other than stdout, or add support for command-line params to your script to run in verbose/quiet mode.

Comment: You could always spit logging information out `stderr` and the data (version number) information out `stdout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.  The return value of a *nix-style executable is an unsigned integer from 0-255.  That usually indicates if it failed or not, but you *could* co-opt it for your own uses.

In this case, I don't think a single unsigned byte is enough.  Thus, you need to output it some other way.  You have a few options

1. The simplest (and probably best in this case) is to continue outputting your output data on `stdout`, and send your logs/debugging information somewhere else.  That could be to a file, or (it's sort-of what it's for) `stderr`
2. Output your data to a file (such as one given in a command line parameter)
3. Arrange some kind of named pipe scheme.  In practice, this is pretty much the same thing as sending it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an executable python script that prints a variable `print 99`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 99
```

`chmod a+x test.py` to set it as executable.

From bash do this `a=$(./test.py)` and if you print `a`(`echo $a`) you should get `99`.

To get only the `version number`, you should print only the `version number`.